# autofocus not working in modal bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

autofocus works only first time when page is loaded next time when I launch model, autofocus does not work in input type

```
<div class="modal fade" id="OrganModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog mainModal">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Organ List</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="divSearch orgsearch" tabindex="1">
          <div class="SearchBox">
            <input type="text" onkeyup="OrganSearch()" id="btnTextOrgan" placeholder="Search" autofocus="autofocus" />
          </div>
          <div class="SearchAction">
            <div class="SearchActionAlign">
              <a href="#" onclick="clearSearchResultOfOrgan()" class="NonAction ActionClick">
                <img src="../../assets/images/icons/close.png" alt="Cancel" class="ImgClose" />
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="organList" class="organ_list"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because bootstrap apply `tabindex=-1` on the modal which remove the `autofocus`...So try to use `shown.bs.modal` method of bootstrap modal

***Stack Snippet***

```js
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  $(this).find('[autofocus]').focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @DipGirase could you share a working example for this...it will be easy to resolve the issue

Comment: inside the drop down in following list code <li class="PIListOption" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#OrganModal" onclick="loadSelectOrgan()">
                        <a class="ActionClick ResizeText">Organ</a>
                    </li>

Comment: function loadSelectOrgan() {
        //var x = document.getElementById("btnTextOrgan").autofocus;
         //document.getElementById("organList").innerHTML = x;        
        organ = JSON.parse(getList(cust_list.utility.ofOrgan, []));
        organListControl.empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < organ.length; i++) {
            $('<div class="orglist" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="update_organ(this)">').appendTo(organListControl).text(organ[i].text).attr("data-seq", organ[i].id);
            $('<hr class="line">"').appendTo(organListControl);
        }
    }

Comment: thanks help.   $(document).on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
   $(this).find('[autofocus]').focus();
 });   this above code is working in my code

Answer (score 2):

Add `autofocus` attribute to `input` in modal after that.

add this in script

```
$('#yourModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
      $(this).find('[autofocus]').focus();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am also use this code

```
<script>
    function autoFocus(){
        $('#searchModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            $('#q').focus();
        });
    }
</script>
```

Where **#searchModal** is modal div ID and **#q** is input element ID

Use this code in button

```
<button type="button" onclick="autoFocus()">Open Modal</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myModal = document.getElementById('myModal')
var myInput = document.getElementById('myInput')

myModal.addEventListener('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  myInput.focus()
})
```

Comment: Why is this preferred over the other answers? And, in particular, the top-voted, accepted answer from a few years ago? Can you [edit] your answer to offer an explanation of what you’re doing?